# Dividing the image into three sizes in PHP

Tags: php, image, storage

I am actually trying to make an image into three sizes and then storing them in the server folder with different names. I am getting this image data in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded format through the mobile client side. Here is the code where I am trying to convert the image into three images.

This is the PHP file where I am receiving data.

```
$uploadPath  = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/OSFiles/of-images/images/';

if(!is_dir($uploadPath))
    mkdir($uploadPath,true) or trigger_error("Can't Create Folder");

$file   = tempnam($uploadPath, 'image');
$fp     = fopen($file, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $binary);   //$binary is--> I am reading the image in binary as I am getting the photo data in base64 encoded format through mobile client side. So I decoded it to binary.

fclose($fp);

$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO oc_t_item_resource(fk_i_item_id, s_name,s_extension,s_content_type, s_path)
        VALUES('$lastid','$s_name','$extension','$s_content_type','$imagepath')");

$imagelastid = mysql_insert_id();

// Create normal size
$normal_path = $path = $uploadPath . $imagelastid . '.jpg' ;
$size = explode('x', '640x480') ;

ImageResizer::fromFile($file)->resizeTo($size[0], $size[1])->saveToFile($path) ;

// Create preview
$path = $uploadPath . $imagelastid . '_preview.jpg' ;
$size = explode('x', '480x340') ;
ImageResizer::fromFile($file)->resizeTo($size[0], $size[1])->saveToFile($path) ;

// Create thumbnail
$path = $uploadPath . $imagelastid . '_thumbnail.jpg' ;
$size = explode('x', '240x200') ;
ImageResizer::fromFile($file)->resizeTo($size[0], $size[1])->saveToFile($path) ;
```

This is my **ImageResizer** class which is in ImageResizer.php file.

```
<?php
    class ImageResizer {

        public static function fromFile($imagePath) {
            return new ImageResizer($imagePath);
        }

        private $im;

        private function __construct($imagePath) {
            if(!file_exists($imagePath)) throw new Exception("$imagePath does not exist!");
            if(!is_readable($imagePath)) throw new Exception("$imagePath is not readable!");
            if(filesize($imagePath)==0) throw new Exception("$imagePath is corrupt or broken!");

            if(osc_use_imagick()) {
                $this->im = new Imagick($imagePath);
            } else {
                $content = file_get_contents($imagePath);
                $this->im = imagecreatefromstring($content);
            }

            return $this;
        }

        public function __destruct() {
            if(osc_use_imagick()) {
                $this->im->destroy();
            } else {
                imagedestroy($this->im);
            }
        }

        public function resizeTo($width, $height) {
            if(osc_use_imagick()) {
                $bg = new Imagick();
                $bg->newImage($width, $height, 'white');

                $this->im->thumbnailImage($width, $height, true);
                $geometry = $this->im->getImageGeometry();

                $x = ( $width - $geometry['width'] ) / 2;
                $y = ( $height - $geometry['height'] ) / 2;

                $bg->compositeImage( $this->im, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x, $y );
                $this->im = $bg;
            } else {
                $w = imagesx($this->im);
                $h = imagesy($this->im);

                if(($w/$h)>=($width/$height)) {
                    //$newW = $width;
                    $newW = ($w > $width)? $width : $w;
                    $newH = $h * ($newW / $w);
                } else {
                    //$newH = $height;
                    $newH = ($h > $height)? $height : $h;
                    $newW = $w * ($newH / $h);
                }

                $newIm = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);//$newW, $newH);
                imagealphablending($newIm, false);
                $colorTransparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($newIm, 255, 255, 255, 127);
                imagefill($newIm, 0, 0, $colorTransparent);
                imagesavealpha($newIm, true);
                imagecopyresampled($newIm, $this->im, (($width-$newW)/2), (($height-$newH)/2), 0, 0, $newW, $newH, $w, $h);
                imagedestroy($this->im);

                $this->im = $newIm;
            }
            return $this;
        }

        public function saveToFile($imagePath) {
            if(file_exists($imagePath) && !is_writable($imagePath)) throw new Exception("$imagePath is not writable!");
            if(osc_use_imagick()) {
                $this->im->setImageFileName($imagePath);
                $this->im->writeImage($imagePath);
            } else {
                imagejpeg($this->im, $imagePath);
            }
        }

        public function show() {
            header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=image.jpg');
            header('Content-type: image/jpg');
            if(osc_use_imagick()) {
            } else {
                imagepng($this->im);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The image is not getting stored at all in the images folder. Where am I going wrong?

A code snippet with corrections would be appreciated.

(I am new to [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), so please be gentle.)

Comment: Any error messages? Can you upload a file without the resizing step?

Comment: @ethrbunny Yeah. I can upload the image without the resizing step, if I save that temporary image by renaming it. Please suggest.

Comment: OK - so which steps did you bypass to get it working?

Comment: Add `error_log($imagePath);` to your `saveToFile` method, so that you can see what `$imagePath` is being passed in.

Comment: Are you using ImageResizer class independently of osclassfields? Or this is some extension to osclassfields? If you are using this class independently, function `osc_use_imagick()` wont work and if you have errors display disabled, you will not notice that error.

Comment: @traditional Exactly, you are right. I am making use of osclassfields independently in my code to make a server support for my mobile application.

Comment: ok then, I have tried your code and it threw error about `osc_use_imagick` function. Turning that if condition into `if (function_exists('osc_use_imagick'))` will always skip the if part and only execute else part. That I have confirmed working.  Though it wont be a nice idea to edit `ImageResizer` class. May be bit of hack if you can live with. Try creating function `osc_use_imagick` that always returns `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `error_reporting( -1 )` when searching for bugs. Then you just follow the messages and fix all the errors.

You skipped one parameter for [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php). $mode is ignored on Windows, but it should be passed anyway in order to get to the $recursive parameter: `mkdir( $uploadPath, 0777, true )`.

Also, you should have a function `osc_use_imagick` included somewhere. I don't have it so I had to change conditions from `if( osc_use_imagick() )` to `if( function_exists( 'osc_use_imagick' ) && osc_use_imagick() )`.

And by the way, you forget to delete your temporary file after all the resizes. Add `unlink( $file )` to the end of the script.